# How do I combine two dependant variables from multivariable normal distribution and recalculate the covariances?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, normal-distribution, finance

Note: Sorry if my notation is slightly off, my background is engineering not pure maths and I'm used to (loose notation).

I have a multivariable normal distribution:

$$x \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{x}, \Sigma_x)$$

where:

$$x=x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n$$
$$\bar{x}=\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2},\bar{x_3},...,\bar{x_n}$$
$$\Sigma_x=\begin{bmatrix} 
\sigma_{x_1}^2 & cov(x_1,x_2) & ... & cov(x_1,x_n)
\\ cov(x_2,x_1) & \sigma_{x_2}^2 & ... & ...
\\ ... & ... & ... & ...
\\ cov(x_n,x_1) & ... & ... & \sigma_{x_n}^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

If i were to combine 2 of these variables, $$ x_n, x_{n-1}$$
Such that:
$$\bar{x_{new}} = w_n*\bar{x_n}+w_{n-1}*\bar{x_{n-1}}$$
$$\sigma_{x_{new}}^2 = w_n^2\sigma_{x_{n}}^2 + w_{n-1}^2\sigma_{x_{n-1}}^2 + 2w_nw_{n-1}cov(n,n_{-1})$$

I have the mean and variance of my new combined variable, but how does the covariance of this new variable update with each other variable? I.E. what is each new $$cov(x_{new},x_i),cov(x_i,x_{new})$$
for $$i -> n-2 $$

I am willing to update any notation if someone believes this is wildly unclear

Comment: is $x_{new} = w_nx_n + w_{n-1}x_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: The diagonal elements of $\Sigma_x$ are incorrect, they should be squared.

Comment: Thanks @Digitallis, you are correct I have updated $$\Sigma_x$$ Yes, the new variable would be the weighted sum of the two others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint :**

Recall that  for random variables $X,Y,Z$ and constants $c$ we have

$$ \text{Cov}(X + Y,Z) = \text{Cov}(X,Z) + \text{Cov}(Y,Z)$$
$$ \text{Cov}(cX,Y) =c \cdot \text{Cov}(X,Y).$$

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware if this relation. So that implies...

$$Cov(X_{new},X_1) = Cov(W_nX_n+W_{n-1}X_{n-1},X_1) = W_nCov(X_n,X_1)+W_{n-1}Cov(X_{n-1},X_1)$$ 

For the case of the covariance of $X_{new}$ with $X_1$

Comment: I would need to algorithmically run that expression for each $X_i$ for $i < n-1$ to correct my $\Sigma_x$

Comment: What do you mean by "correcting my $\Sigma_x$ ? $\Sigma_x$ is the variance covariance matrix of the random vector $X = (X_1,...,X_n)$. The  value of $Cov(X_{new},X_i)$ does not appear in this matrix. Unless your are now updating the vector $X$ to be $( X_1,...,X_n,X_{new})$ in which case it would make sense to "correct" $\Sigma_x$

Comment: Yes exactly that, the context behind this question in grouping sets of variables together but keeping track of their dependence on each other. While correcting doesn't make sense from a mathematical point of view, as soon as those variables are combined $\Sigma_x$ will need updating. It's memory allocation will be too large as the number of rows and columns have changed if we wish to represent this new set of variables as a fresh distribution. I suppose 'Defining a new $\Sigma_{\hat{x}}$ is a better phrasing?'